# String emptiness checker annotation

Tags: java, android, annotations

I am trying to write an annotation that will help me find out if the String assigned to memberVariable of a model class is empty or not. If empty than don't proceed with registration.

I have written the following code but I am confused as how will I tell the Annotation, what value to check and how will the annotation notify me if the String is empty.

**IsStringEmpty.java**

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface IsStringEmpty {
    String value();
}
```

**StringEmptinessChecker.java**

```
public class StringEmptinessChecker {
    public boolean process(Object instance) {
        Class<?> clazz = instance.getClass();
        for (Method m : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (m.isAnnotationPresent(IsStringEmpty.class)) {
                IsStringEmpty annotation = m.getAnnotation(IsStringEmpty.class);
                String val = annotation.value();
                return val.isEmpty();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public void foo() {
    MyModel model = new MyModel();

    @IsStringEmpty()??????????
    model.setName(nameET.getText().toString());
    // if nameEt.getText().toString() is empty. Dont make network call for registratoin
}
```

Comment: How about plain old `if (!nameEt.getText().toString().isEmpty()) { makeNetworkCall(); }`? Or a method `setNameAndCallNetworkIfNonEmpty(model, nameEt.getText().toString())`? Using annotation processing for "magic" might just make your code harder to follow.

Comment: I understand but I am trying to learn annotations therefore I am pposting this question here

Comment: Anyone here to help?